# Looping through JSON object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

For some *development technologies* and their *projects* data, I am trying to get keys and values using `for` loop.

I am trying to make separate section of *development technologies* and then trying to put their *projects* inside that section, but I am not able to iterate, please tell what is wrong with my code.

[image]

I am able to access all *web technologies* but don't know how to run nested loop

```
var projects = {
  ReactJs: {
    project: {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Health",
      technologies: "XD, HTML5, CSS, ReactNative, Redux",
      description: "Tripsafe is an app designed  to address cross-border travel issues both nationally and internationally. With automated uploads from Pathologists, Doctors or any health professional relating to tests, certificates, letters and or official visas, everyone can check, verify and confirm that the document seen is a true immutable digital copy.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        "techname": "ReactJs",
        "techname": "ReactNative"
      }
    },
    project: {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Event management",
      description: "In this app you can apply to be a member of the United Leuva of Houston if accepted you can then receive information about the organization via this application.To get the latest news about United Leuva Houston you it would be via this app.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        "techname": "XD",
        "techname": "HTML5",
        "techname": "CSS",
        "techname": "ReactNative",
        "techname": "Redux",
      }
    },
    project: {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Hospitality",
      description: "This app is intended to be used in the hospitality industry. The app RoomCheck is an in-house product of SJRP Systems. The app streamlines processes for housekeeping and maintenance by making their work and work progress real time.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        "techname": "ReactNative",
        "techname": "Redux",
      }
    }
  },
  ReactNative: {
    project: {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Health",
      technologies: "XD, HTML5, CSS, ReactNative, Redux",
      description: "Tripsafe is an app designed  to address cross-border travel issues both nationally and internationally. With automated uploads from Pathologists, Doctors or any health professional relating to tests, certificates, letters and or official visas, everyone can check, verify and confirm that the document seen is a true immutable digital copy.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        "techname": "ReactJs",
        "techname": "ReactNative"
      }
    },
    project: {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Event management",
      description: "In this app you can apply to be a member of the United Leuva of Houston if accepted you can then receive information about the organization via this application.To get the latest news about United Leuva Houston you it would be via this app.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        "techname": "XD",
        "techname": "HTML5",
        "techname": "CSS",
        "techname": "ReactNative",
        "techname": "Redux",
      }
    },
    project: {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Hospitality",
      description: "This app is intended to be used in the hospitality industry. The app RoomCheck is an in-house product of SJRP Systems. The app streamlines processes for housekeeping and maintenance by making their work and work progress real time.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        "techname": "ReactNative",
        "techname": "Redux",
      }
    }
  }
}


var data = '';

for ( var key in projects ) { 
  var holderkey = key
  for ( var innerkey in projects[holderkey]) {
    var holderkey_n = innerkey
    console.log(projects[holderkey][holderkey_n])
   }
  data += holderkey_n
}

document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = data;
```

Comment: `don't know how to run nested loop` you're already running a nested loop...

Comment: Actually brother it is not working correctly ,

Comment: Maybe add more infos about how it's "not working correctly" so we can help you. Right now it sounds like you want us to build a thing...

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to do. Based on your `projects` variable, the projects are already grouped by the technology. Also, an object shouldn't have identical keys, so within `ReactJS`, you shouldn't have 3 `project` keys. Instead, store each project as an item in an array

Comment: In first loop I want to fetch all development technologies and in nested loop I want to fetch all project related to that technology, but It is messing whole code, do you have any idea, please take a look to the image , that I have attached,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `array` instead of `object` on the project level. An object cannot have the same keys inside. In that case, you have to use `array` instead.

```js
var projects = {
  ReactJs: [
    {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Health",
      technologies: "XD, HTML5, CSS, ReactNative, Redux",
      description:
        "Tripsafe is an app designed  to address cross-border travel issues both nationally and internationally. With automated uploads from Pathologists, Doctors or any health professional relating to tests, certificates, letters and or official visas, everyone can check, verify and confirm that the document seen is a true immutable digital copy.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        techname: "ReactJs",
        techname: "ReactNative",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Event management",
      description:
        "In this app you can apply to be a member of the United Leuva of Houston if accepted you can then receive information about the organization via this application.To get the latest news about United Leuva Houston you it would be via this app.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        techname: "XD",
        techname: "HTML5",
        techname: "CSS",
        techname: "ReactNative",
        techname: "Redux",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Hospitality",
      description:
        "This app is intended to be used in the hospitality industry. The app RoomCheck is an in-house product of SJRP Systems. The app streamlines processes for housekeeping and maintenance by making their work and work progress real time.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        techname: "ReactNative",
        techname: "Redux",
      },
    },
  ],
  ReactNative: [
    {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Health",
      technologies: "XD, HTML5, CSS, ReactNative, Redux",
      description:
        "Tripsafe is an app designed  to address cross-border travel issues both nationally and internationally. With automated uploads from Pathologists, Doctors or any health professional relating to tests, certificates, letters and or official visas, everyone can check, verify and confirm that the document seen is a true immutable digital copy.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        techname: "ReactJs",
        techname: "ReactNative",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Event management",
      description:
        "In this app you can apply to be a member of the United Leuva of Houston if accepted you can then receive information about the organization via this application.To get the latest news about United Leuva Houston you it would be via this app.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        techname: "XD",
        techname: "HTML5",
        techname: "CSS",
        techname: "ReactNative",
        techname: "Redux",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "Lorem Ipsum",
      industry: "Hospitality",
      description:
        "This app is intended to be used in the hospitality industry. The app RoomCheck is an in-house product of SJRP Systems. The app streamlines processes for housekeeping and maintenance by making their work and work progress real time.",
      img: "project/img",
      tech: {
        techname: "ReactNative",
        techname: "Redux",
      },
    },
  ],
};

var data = "";

for (var tech in projects) {
  console.log(`----- ${tech} related projects -----`)
  for (var project of projects[tech]) {
    console.log(project);
  }
}
```